# Why does gas pressure affect work function?

Tags: material-science, photoelectric-effect

A while back I did an experiment at my university in which I used high vacuum (about 10-7 torr) to measure the work function of a tungsten filament. We had to measure the partial pressures and register the work functions depending on the pressure. I did not ask back then, but now I was wondering, why does pressure affect the work function of a material? 
Since the work function is a characteristic of the material, and the photocurrent depends only on the incoming photon and said function, I would think it is irrelevant. Why is this not the case?

Comment: Work function is a surface property. For example, it is also different for (111) surfaces and (110) surfaces.

Comment: @NickHeumann Describe how the work function depends on pressure.

Comment: From what I know, the work function is affected by the condition of its surface, so at different pressures there will be different amounts of adsorption of gas molecules on the surface, which I think should affect the work function. However, I am not sure if this is correct, and I am having trouble confirming or refuting it